# How to add hardcoded value to WMI output in Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, csv, wmi

I am new to powershell, i am trying to retrieve the SQL Services details using WMI object. My code is as follows:

---

```
$InputFile = Import-Csv "C:\input\Servers.csv" | %{ $_.Instance = $_.Instance -replace "\\.*?$" ; $_}
Write-Output "SQL Services details for Server:" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG 
Write-Output "********************************" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG  -Append
foreach($Servers in $Inputfile)
{

Write-Output $Servers|ft -AutoSize | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG 
$Servicesstate=Get-WmiObject win32_service  -ComputerName $Servers.instance  | Select Name, Startmode, State  | Where-Object `
{$_.name -like "*SQL*" -and $_.Startmode -match "Auto" -and $_.state -match "Stopped"} | ft -auto 
if (!$Servicesstate )
{
Write-Host "No Services in STOP state"
Write-Output "No Services in STOPPED state" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG -Append
}
Else
{
echo ($Servicesstate )
Write-Output ($Servicesstate)  | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG  -Append
}
}
```

---

My Output will come something like this:

```
Instance Name:
ABCDEFGH

Name                                    Startmode State  

SQLdmCollectionService$Default          Auto      Stopped
SQLdmManagementService$Default          Auto      Stopped
SQLdmPredictiveAnalyticsService$Default Auto      Stopped
```

---

My question is, how to add a additional column to the output and add custom text as values.

I want to add remarks column and display failed if any services are stopped.

---

```
Name                                    Startmode State   Remarks

SQLdmCollectionService$Default          Auto      Stopped  Failed
SQLdmManagementService$Default          Auto      Stopped  Failed
SQLdmPredictiveAnalyticsService$Default Auto      Stopped  Failed
```

---

Comment: thank you for formatting the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning your values to `$servicestate` you can pipe to a `Select` command and create an extra value with a hashtable. Check out this slightly modified version of your script, paying close attention to line 9:

```
$InputFile = Import-Csv "C:\input\Servers.csv" | %{ $_.Instance = $_.Instance -replace "\\.*?$" ; $_}
Write-Output "SQL Services details for Server:" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG 
Write-Output "********************************" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG  -Append
foreach($Servers in $Inputfile)
{

    Write-Output $Servers|ft -AutoSize | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG 
    $Servicesstate=Get-WmiObject win32_service  -ComputerName $Servers.instance  | Select Name, Startmode, State  |
    Where{$_.name -like "*SQL*" -and $_.Startmode -match "Auto" -and $_.state -match "Stopped"}|Select Name,Startmode,State,@{l='Remarks';e={if($_.State -eq "Stopped"){"Failed"}}}
    if (!$Servicesstate )
    {
        Write-Host "No Services in STOP state"
        Write-Output "No Services in STOPPED state" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG -Append
    }
    Else
    {
        echo ($Servicesstate|ft -AutoSize )
        Write-Output ($Servicesstate)  |FT -auto| Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG  -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm. It returned error first but then i added quotes to Remark Column fixed the error     {l='Remarks';e={if($_.State -eq "Stopped")

Comment: I'm all about being parsimonious when you're typing stuff by hand, but for the sake of readability in a script, let's use `{label='Remarks';expression={if($_.State -eq "Stopped")`, eh?

Comment: @BenThul I virtually always provide code as I would have written it for myself, to help those unaware of some shortcuts or aliases, and because it seems more natural to me. If people have questions about, or need help understanding the code that I have provided I'm always happy to break it down and explain it (including any short hand used). Also, I updated my answer to fix 'Remarks' (added quotes).

Answer (score 2):

Your columns are defined by what you put in Select-Object, as you only have Name, Startmode and State those will be the columns.

Change

`Select Name,Startmode,State`

To

`Select-Object Name,Startmode,State,Remark`

By adding another property called Remarks you will effectively add another column to your output and you can change the value of Remark by calling the property like so

`$Servicestate.Remark = 'Failed'`

So you're final code might look something like this

```
$InputFile = Import-Csv "C:\input\Servers.csv" | %{ $_.Instance = $_.Instance -replace "\\.*?$" ; $_}
Write-Output "SQL Services details for Server:" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG 
Write-Output "********************************" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG  -Append
foreach($Servers in $Inputfile)
{

Write-Output $Servers|ft -AutoSize | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG 
$Servicesstate=Get-WmiObject win32_service  -ComputerName $Servers.instance  | Select Name, Startmode, State  | Where-Object `
{$_.name -like "*SQL*" -and $_.Startmode -match "Auto" -and $_.state -match "Stopped"} | ft -auto 
if (!$Servicesstate )
{
    # Edit the new column before you output
    $Servicestate.Remark = 'Failed'
    Write-Host "No Services in STOP state"
    Write-Output "No Services in STOPPED state" | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG -Append
}
Else
{
    # Edit the new column before you output
    $Servicestate.Remark = 'Success'
    echo ($Servicesstate )
    Write-Output ($Servicesstate)  | Out-File C:\output\SQLCHECK.STOPPED.LOG  -Append
}
}
```

Comment: i am getting error when i used $Servicesstate.Remark = 'Failed'                                                            <pre> <code> Property 'Remark' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:17 char:1
+ $Servicestate.Remark = 'Failed'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound